# i want to configure the git to log oneline format persistently

Tags: git

I just have found `log.decorate` setting but it isn't.
Is there way to just type`git log` and receive such an output

```
756318c message3
a5001f4 message2
339d5e3 message1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this to your `~/.gitconfig`:

```
 [format]
   pretty = format:%h %s
```

Alternatively, as [r45i suggests in the comment below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36221695/i-want-to-configure-the-git-to-log-oneline-format-persistently/36221843#comment60075978_36221843), to have the output colorised:

```
 [format]
   pretty = format:%C(auto) %h %s
```

See `format.pretty` on [git-config(1)](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-config.html) and `--pretty=...` on [git-log(1)](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-log.html)

Comment: It is that but a logged text became uncolored oO

Comment: I found a solution. Just add `%C(auto)` to a format

Comment: Your example didn't have any colors, so I assumed you didn't want them :)

I'll add your variant for the next guy who reads.

Answer (score 0):

I guess it's something what you want:

https://coderwall.com/p/euwpig/a-better-git-log

Comment: Post is i don't want to write this command every time) i can wtite bash alias but...